# Ruby debugging: how to step over inline breakpoints

Tags: ruby, debugging

How to step over pieces of single line while debugging in ruby?

*What I'm looking for - is ability to step by commands while executing line, move over line parts, calling its separate methods, function by function. Ability to separately step over multiple functions in line.*

Like in javascript (screenshot from Chrome console):

[image]

For example, here I don't need to step into previously chained method call `all(promises)`, but need to go right into `then`.

Seems to be essential functionality for modern programming language, though can't find how to do it in ruby. For now I have to **step into** each function in line and **finish** it's execution to trap into next function call - repeating it till I get into needed chained function - it's monkey job now :).

Disclaimer: There could be opinions, that I could avoid methods chaining, but it **is** convenient. (Generally, looking for convenient ways of work and tools for it)

Comment: you could place them on separate lines `ruby` does not mind this. If the previous line ends with a dot (`.`), or the next line starts with one, the next line will pick up as if they were inline. **caveat: IRB does not like the next line starting with a dot portion but in file code it will perform fine**

Comment: as far as I know @engineersmnky 's solution is the only one which is a hassle, especially when stepping through library code

Comment: Your question is too broad. We don't know what you are using to debug. And, you are asking us for tools to do it, which is asking for recommendations, which is off-topic.

Comment: Respected mr. @theTinMan , if you don't understand question - it doesn't always mean, that question is too broad.

I'm using ruby to debug ruby scripts and asking for ways, to solve specific clearly marked task - either with standard debugger or some library (if any exists).

Please, read "What is a recommendation question?" in meta, and cancel your down-vote on this topic

Comment: I understand the question, and use debuggers in all languages I write in, because single-stepping is essential to understanding a problem in code. I also understand what SO wants in questions.

Answer (score 0):

Debug library which allows to step into function by name with `step func_name`:

https://github.com/garmoshka-mo/pry-moves

[image]

*here `s` is shortcut for `step`*